# Is there a way to split a dataframe by zip?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which is generated in a previous step.

```
num_seq  phys_red  dam_fac  lost_frac_damage
0      10000         1      0.1          0.097761
1      10000         1      0.2          0.200825
2      10000         1      0.3          0.291385
3      10000         1      0.4          0.406255
4      10000         1      0.5          0.488418
..       ...       ...      ...               ...
173    10000        20      0.5          0.000000
174    10000        20      0.6          0.000130
175    10000        20      0.7          0.001480
176    10000        20      0.8          0.011885
177    10000        20      0.9          0.130718
```

I want to split it into five dataframes, `df1, df2, df3, df4, df5`, based on the value in the column `dam_fac`.

My approach was via zip:

```
dam_vals = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

for df, dam in zip(dfs,dam_vals):
    df = df.drop(df[df.dam_fac != dam].index)
```

However, this code gives me an error message:

"NameError: name 'df1' is not defined".

How can I solve this problem via zip? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with assign list of DataFrames to variables like:

```
dam_vals = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 = [df[df.dam_fac == n] for n in dam_vals]
print (df1)
   num_seq  phys_red  dam_fac  lost_frac_damage
0    10000         1      0.1          0.097761
```

Another idea is create list of DataFrames `dfs`, for selecting is used indexing:

```
dfs = [df[df.dam_fac == n] for n in dam_vals]
print (dfs[0])
   num_seq  phys_red  dam_fac  lost_frac_damage
0    10000         1      0.1          0.097761
```